# Each different multiple text line respectively affect position of image where placed above the multiple text

Tags: html, css

What I did

```
enter code here
```

https://jsfiddle.net/shc36gd9/18/

What i want

1) different multiple text line don't affect the position of images

2) Fix the position of images ( at top )

Comment: Used `vertical-align: top;`  in `.ui-mini-list__content li`, when used `display: inline-block` by default alignment was baseline.

Comment: @MinalChauhan My God.. Thank you.. You save my life!

Comment: Welcome, choose my answer if it helped so other people can know this one is solved :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Used `vertical-align: top;` in `.ui-mini-list__content li`,

when used `display: inline-block` by default alignment was baseline.

Here is your updated [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shc36gd9/21/)